Cropperjs or Javascript issues uploading cropped image to the server with php
Please help me with this:
  <h5 style="color: <?php if (isset($color)) { echo $color; } ?>;"><?php if (isset($statusupload)) { echo $statusupload; } ?></h5>
  <form action="index.php" method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="labelforsubmit" for="uploadInput">Choose your image...</label>
    <input important type="file" id="uploadInput" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="openModal()">
    <br>
    <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image Preview"></img>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnsubmit" name="submit_file"></input>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <h3>Crop Image</h3>
      <div>
        <img id="cropperPreview" src="#" alt="Cropped Image Preview">
      </div>
      <button onclick="applyCroppedImage()">Apply Cropped Image</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.12/cropper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/image-compressor.js/2.1.0/image-compressor.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var cropper;
    var selectedImageBase64;

    function openModal() {
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      modal.style.display = "block";

      if (cropper) {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
      }

      var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
      var file = document.getElementById('uploadInput').files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function() {
        selectedImageBase64 = reader.result;
        var cropperPreview = document.getElementById('cropperPreview');
        cropperPreview.src = selectedImageBase64;
        initializeCropperInstance();
      }

      if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        preview.src = "";
      }
    }

    function closeModal() {
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    function initializeCropperInstance() {
      var image = document.getElementById('cropperPreview');
      cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        viewMode: 1,
        autoCropArea: 1,
        movable: true,
        zoomable: true,
        rotatable: true,
        scalable: true,
        cropBoxResizable: true,
        cropBoxMovable: true,
      });
    }

    function applyCroppedImage() {
      cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          var base64data = reader.result;
          var croppedImagePreview = document.getElementById('preview');
          croppedImagePreview.src = base64data;
          closeModal();
        };
      }, 'image/jpeg', 0.6);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Cropperjs or Javascript issues uploading cropped image to the server with php.
This is the index.php file, and I've integrated cropperjs to allow users to crop their selected images before uploading them. While the cropping feature is functional, the issue is that the original, uncropped image is still being uploaded to the server instead of the cropped version. I suspect that the cropperjs is not updating the file input in the form, or the cropped image data from JavaScript is not being passed to the file input, resulting in the upload of the original image size rather than the cropped image. Please assist me in resolving this issue.
here's the link of my website that working on.

As per [ask] you must provide a [mre] of your issue within your question, not a full code dump somewhere else. You can [edit] your post. Otherwise it will probably be closed. Also there's no need for the monster bold text over a whole paragraph. Remember to check the preview box before posting. Thanks

Thanks. So yeah as far as I can see it just puts the cropped image into a preview but doesn't actually add the data to a form element which would get submitted to the server. A hidden field would probably be appropriate

hi @adyson, how can I resolve that issue?

By writing some JS code which puts the base64 data into a hidden field in your form

I'm uncertain because I'm still in the process of learning it.

can you send code please T-T?

https://www.google.com/search?q=js+write+variable+to+hidden+field - it's not an uncommon process so you can quite easily research the principle, I doubt we need to repeat it again.

You don't need to reinvent the wheel for typical situations.
Let's see a sample demo for "PHP Crop Image While Uploading with Cropper JS" here.
You can read the full article and download the source code here.
(Even if you want to practice, you can read this code first and then use its approach to write yours.)
I hope it helps.
